# How do I store and call a temporary variable in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

Apologies in advance! Beginner here. I'm finding myself using a feature more and more often like this one I'm going to describe, to store a temporary variable and recalling it. I tried looking it up, but haven't found an answer specifically related to my issue.

I'm trying to do something very simple, once I understand how it's done I can apply it to other types (etc).

Let's say I want to change the color of a light, but store the original light setting in a variable, then recall that setting once the timer has run out. This is for a game in Unity.

```
if (powerupEnabled)
        {
            CameraShake.instance.shakeDuration = 5;
            powerupTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            snakeheadFire.SetActive(true);
            //lightIngame.intensity = 0.8f;
            Color original_color = lightIngame.color; // <<<< Trying to store original color set in game in variable
                            
            lightIngame.color = Color.red;
            if (lightIngame != null)
            {
                // add the amount of time that has passed since last frame
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

                // if the amount of time passed is greater than or equal to the delay
                if (timeElapsed >= delay)
                {
                    // reset the time elapsed
                    timeElapsed = 0;
                    // toggle the light
                    
                    ToggleLight();
                }
            }
            if (powerupTimer <= 0)
            {
                lightIngame.color = original_color; // <<<< Trying to restore original color set in game from variable
                CameraShake.instance.shakeDuration = 0;
                lightIngame.intensity = 1.12f;
                print("Timer stopped!");
                powerupTimer = 5f;
                snakeheadFire.SetActive(false);
                powerupEnabled = false;
            }
        }
```

So basically I tried Color original_color = lightIngame.color, but once I call original color back, the light won't change to its original setting. The two lines (color changes) are referenced with '<<<<'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temp variable is created every frame, if that function runs every frame. You need a variable that can survive until your `powerupTimer` runs out.

I suggest this:

```
private Color temp_value; // this lives in the class, not in the function.
void Update()
{
    if (powerupEnabled)
    {
        // do stuff

        if (powerupTimer <= 0)
        {
            setPowerupState(false); // disable powerup
        }
    }
}
void setPowerupState(bool enabled)
{
    powerupEnabled = enabled;
    if(enabled)
        temp_value = lightIngame.color; // store the original color once, not every frame.
    else
        lightIngame.color = temp_value; // restore the saved value.
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much for taking the time to read and answer my question! It works like a charm! It may seem basic and silly but you have no idea how valuable this info is, I can apply this to any temp value I need (which is quite often), and I understand now how temp values can be stored.

Comment: If you use a Coroutine you could avoid the local field completely! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385616/7111561)

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383816/7111561) already provides an explanation and one possible solution.

You could, however, avoid the local variable completely by not processing this in `Update` every frame but using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) where local variables exist for the entire lifetime of that routine:

```
void Update()
{
    if (powerupEnabled)
    {
        // Make sure to start the routine only once
        powerupEnabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine());
    }
}

private IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine()
{
    CameraShake.instance.shakeDuration = 5;
    snakeheadFire.SetActive(true);

    var original_color = lightIngame.color;

    lightIngame.color = Color.red;

    var powerupTimer = 5f;
    var timeElapsed = 0f;
    while(powerupTimer > 0 && lightIngame)
    {
        // add the amount of time that has passed since last frame
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

        // if the amount of time passed is greater than or equal to the delay
        if (timeElapsed >= delay)
        {
            // reset the time elapsed
            timeElapsed = 0;
            // toggle the light
                    
            ToggleLight();
        }

        // This tells Unity to "pause" this routine, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;

        powerupTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
        
    lightIngame.color = original_color; 
    CameraShake.instance.shakeDuration = 0;
    lightIngame.intensity = 1.12f;
    print("Timer stopped!");
    snakeheadFire.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# has two different types of objects: value types and reference types.
Value types are simple types, like int, bool, double etc.

For the most part, all other / more complex classes are reference types, meaning when you assign a variable to another, instead of copying the object, C# will just assign the memory address of the object.

This means, when you call `Color original_color = lightIngame.color;`, C# will assign the object reference of lightIngame.color to your variable original_color. The value is not copied, but both variables point to the same object.

When you assign a new value to lightIngame.color afterwards, you are changing the value of `lightIngame.color` and `original_color` at the same time, as they both point to the same object.

To fix this, you need to create a copy of `lightIngame.color` when saving it, for example via copy constructors.

This is not a unity-specific issue, but a general fact about how c# works.

Comment: When you run `UnityEngine.Color original_color = lightIngame.color;`, it does NOT assign an object reference. [`UnityEngine.Color` is a struct, which makes it a value type](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `lightIngame.color` is a reference type.

If you deep copy `lightIngame.color` when you are trying to save its state, it might work.

If deep copying is not an option, you can perhaps represent `lightIngame.color` with a proxy value.

For instance, you could perhaps create an enum `ReferenceColours` and when you want to store the value call

`var initialColour = lightIngame.color.ToReferenceColour()`.

When you want to set it back you can do

`lightIngame.color = var initialColour.ToLightInGameColour()`

Note, `ToReferenceColour()` and `ToLightInGameColour()` will have to be extension methods which you create. The logic inside this would simply just handle the mapping between the two.

EDIT - It has been explained via comments on this post that `Color` is really a `UnityEngine.Color` which is a struct. This this means it will be passed by value thus the solution above is unnecessary.

Comment: Color is a struct, it cannot be reference

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN See [the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) for more information about `UnityEngine.Color`.